# how to select html element objects

Tags: javascript, html

If I click on one or two I'll get the object of whole `ul` tag, but from this object I want to get access to the `li` tag objects and I am not able to get how

```js
 function on(a){
   console.log(a);
 }
```

```html
 <ul onclick=on(this)>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

please help me out...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the clicks `event.target` to show which child has been clicked:

```html
<script>
  function on(event) {
    console.log(event.target, event.currentTarget);
    // as Rob points out, there is no need to pass in this as you can access the ul from event.currentTarget
  }
</script>
<ul onclick="on(event)">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need pass event with `on(event,this)` .In Firefox not support without pass event

Comment: There is no need to pass *this* if it's not used. The UL is available as [*event.currentTarget*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Then you should call `on` function in your `li` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    function on(a) {
      console.log(a);
    }
  </script>
  <ul>
    <li onclick=on(this)>one</li>
    <li onclick=on(this)>two</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
  function on(event, a) {
    console.log(event.target);
  }
</script>
<ul onclick="on(event, this)">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you add the listener dynamically, then within the listener the element that called the listener is *this* and the related *event* object is passed as the first argument.

You can get the element that was clicked on using *event.target*, e.g.

```js
function handleClick(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target);
  console.log(evt.currentTarget);
  console.log(this);
}
//*
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('theUL').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}

//*/
```

```html
<ul id="theUL">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```